# Unable to click on a button in Pop-up in Selenium webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a Yes button on a pop-up window in Selenium and not able to do so. HTML code is :

```
<div id="dialoguebuttons">    
    <div style="left: 60px; color: rgb(0, 102, 153); padding-top: 5px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; float: left; position: relative;" id="dialog_question">Activate Riskfirst Rapid?</div>
        <a id="dialogYesButton" class="button btn-orng" tabIndex="101" href="#">
            <span class="btn-inner">Yes</span>
        </a>
        <a id="dialogNoButton" class="button btn-orng" tabIndex="102" href="#">
            <span class="btn-inner">No</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Java code I am trying to execute:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id="save_quote_button"]/span)).click(); // After this the pop-up window gets displayed
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id="dialogYesButton"]/span)).click(); // Trying to click on the Yes button on the pop-up
```

It just skips the step without actually giving any error.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `/span` in `//*[@id="dialogYesButton"]/span`

Comment: You might be able to click the SPAN and get the same effect but as kiran said, I would remove the span and just click the A tag which is indicated by the ID. I would go further and say don't use XPath in simple cases like this. This should work: `driver.findElement(By.id("dialogYesButton")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to click on the Yes button, this xpath may help you:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id="dialoguebuttons"]/a[text()='Yes')).click();`

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firefox browser then install `firebug` Addon and `firepath` Addon  and inspect that element using firepath and paste here that xpath between double quotes mentioned in below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(" ")).click();
```

If you are not familiar with `firebug` refer [this](http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)  link and try it. It will help you out.